# c# SendPingAsync not running to completion

Tags: c#

I'm working on a project that pings a list of addresses and reflects on screen which of those are not pingable. MY current working code simply goes down the list and pings each address one at a time and changes the color of the object's name depending on whether it can be pinged or not.

```
PingReply reply = ping.Send(pos[item.Index].IP, 100);
if (reply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
{
  item.Forecolor = Color.Green;
}
else
{
  item.ForeColor = Color.Red;
}
```

This works just as intended. The problem is that while a ping is active, the UI freezes. In fact, I can't even move the window while that ping is happening. Of course, this only occurs on pings that will fail. I have limited the time a ping request will wait using `100`, but that only helps reduce the amount of time the UI is frozen. So, I looked into asynchronous pinging. Now, I only get negative results. Below is the code I was trying to use.

```
//pertinent part of code
Task<PingReply> result = Ping(pos[item.Index].IP);
if (result.Status == TaskStatus.Running || result.Status == TaskStatus.RanToCompletion)
{
  item.ForeColor = Color.Green;
}
else
{
  item.ForeColor = Color.Red;
}

//elsewhere in the code
public async Task<PingReply> Ping(string address)
{
  var reply = await new Ping().SendPingAsync(address);
  return reply;
}
```

As far as what I'm trying to get this to do, I don't mind if each ping runs through synchronously as long as it's on a separate thread from the UI. I want to be sure that if I'm trying to manipulate the window in some way (adding new locations, moving the window itself, etc.) that a missed ping is not going to interfere with user experience.

I feel like the problem is just what I'm checking for in the condition, but since I don't have working code/logic, the condition may just be the surface of what's wrong here.

Comment: Please also post part with `await` (or maybe `Task.Run`) that shows how do you wait for results to come back... Or maybe you are using completely incorrect `.Wait`/ `.Result` calls?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is hard to see why you are using the task status to determine whether a ping succeeded or not. You probably should examine the `PingReply` just as in the synchronous version.

```
PingReply reply = await Ping(pos[item.Index].IP);
if (reply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
   ...
```

Comment: Useful... Also I think OP needs another duplicate - not how to get results with `await`, but rather how to invoke `async` methods from webForm/WPF event handlers...

Comment: That got it. The fields start out black, so I can even see them update one at a time from black to green or red. Clearly, I'm going to have to go back and learn some more about what is happening here.

Answer (score 0):

You can't update the UI from another thread and as you see you lock up if you perform the ping synchronously on your UI thread.  You have two ways of handling this off of your UI thread then.  The first is to use a `BackgroundWorker` and do the pinging synchronously on the `BackgroundWorker`'s DoWork method and send updates to your UI thread to do the color updates.  You can potentally have lots of BackgroundWorkers doing each one, or just keep reusing the same one with different parameters.

The other is to keep most of code you have, and ping synchronously, but wrapped in a Task using an anon method, and use a `Progress<T>` object with a callback that updates your UI.  This callback will get registered on the UI thread, but can be called from your Task.

Here's an example:

```
Progress prog = new Progress<Tuple<string,bool>>(p => 
{
    String itemName = p.Item1;
    bool success = p.Item2;
   //locate item by name and set to color based on success
}
```

This should be created within a method on your UI, but available to all methods in the class.

You can then call this progress object from your async Ping method, which will marshal data to your UI thread and perform the update for you.